# Changing Chrome app (not browser, but app) from blue to another color?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, skin

You can skin Chrome, but how can I change the default blue top bar color in Chrome application shortcuts? I mean the thing that turns a web app into a pseudo desktop app, reachable via *Page menu -> Create application shortcut*. For some reason it ignores my theme settings... I just want to turn it from light blue to dark blue or something on Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this. In Windows Vista, when you have Theme "Windows Aero" loaded, you can change the color of the windows from control panel > Appearance and PErsononalization> Personalization> Windows colors and Appearance.

You can change the color at this location. Chrome will reflect this setting.

This is for Windows Vista only.

Hope this helps.